# AJAX firing twice (infinite scroll). Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to debug an infinite scroll implementation with AJAX.

---

```
//the-JavaScript
$("#loadingDiv").hide();
var loadIndex = 0;

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){  


            loadIndex = loadIndex + 1;

            $("#loadingDiv").show();
            $.post("ajaxinfinitescroll.php",{loadIndex:loadIndex},function(data){

            setTimeout(function(){

                $("div.loadMoreData").append(data);

                $("#loadingDiv").hide();



            }, 1000); // wait 1 second

            })
        }
    })
```

---

```
//the-PHP
$loadIndex = $_POST['loadIndex'];

echo $loadIndex;
```

---

```
    //the-HTML
    <div class='loadMoreData'></div>
    <div id='loadingDiv'>loadingimage.gif</div>
```

---

After the first time I scroll to the end of the page, I should get a `1` in the HTML output, but I'm getting `12`. The next time I scroll to the end of the page, I should end up with `12` but I actually end up with `1234.`

So, the AJAX seems to be firing twice each time. **Why?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess it should work well, if you change your logic:

```
$(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height()
```

After that you must need to add a flag to check if the new content has been loaded or not and then reinitialize the scrolling function to resume back the old one.

```
// Add a flag
var scrolled = false;
// Change the logic
$(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height()
// allow AJAX call only if not scrolled
if (!scrolled) {
  // immediately, revert the flag:
  scrolled = true;
  $.ajax(function () {
    // inside the AJAX call, restore it
    scrolled = false;
  });
}
```

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister Good question. Lemme answer that.

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work. When I do this, nothing fires. Thinking that perhaps the left side is never able to be **greater than** the right side, I also tried `$(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 1` and that gave the same results as my original post.

Comment: It doesn't fire when the left side is **greater than** the right side.

Comment: @user1883050 I said you need to re-init the AJAX call. Which means, redefine. So the same code will redefine dynamically.

Comment: Not working because the **greater than** condition is never met so nothing gets fired. I tried your idea with an **equal** condition and that's causing the AJAX to fire twice too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98488/discussion-between-praveen-kumar-and-user1883050).

Comment: Thanks Praveen, how do I get into chat? I can give you the source code.

Comment: It eventually worked for me (with help from Praveen via chat), but it didn't work when I used `>` , it only worked when I used `==` in `$(window).scrollTop() > $....`

Comment: @user1883050 Come to Chat.

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep track of the "isLoading" state and stop the autoload behaviour while it's the case.

Even better, remove the scroll even listener while the ajax request is being loaded. Add it back once you get a response.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, I initially tried the following solution, but it didn't work. I implemented the `isLoading` concept via @Louy, but I placed it in the wrong line:

```
//the JavaScript
$("#loadingDiv").hide();
var loadIndex = 0;
var isLoading = false;

if (!isLoading) {
    $(window).scroll(function(){
            if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){

                isLoading = true;
                loadIndex = loadIndex + 1;

                $("#loadingDiv").show();
                $.post("ajaxinfinitescroll.php", {loadIndex:loadIndex},function(data){

                setTimeout(function(){

                    $("div.loadMoreData").append(data);

                    $("#loadingDiv").hide();

                    isLoading = false;

                }, 1000); // wait 1 second

                })
        }
    })
}
```

Then I got help from @Praveen_Kumar, and changed the line where `isLoading` appears, and it worked:

```
//the JavaScript
$("#loadingDiv").hide();
var loadIndex = 0;
var isLoading = false;

$(window).scroll(function(){
   if (!isLoading) {
            if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){

                isLoading = true;
                loadIndex = loadIndex + 1;

                $("#loadingDiv").show();
                $.post("ajaxinfinitescroll.php", {loadIndex:loadIndex},function(data){

                setTimeout(function(){

                    $("div.loadMoreData").append(data);

                    $("#loadingDiv").hide();

                    isLoading = false;

                }, 1000); // wait 1 second

                })
             }
   }
})
```